Improve nnetar() for loop for grid search
I am conducting a grid search with the following function for nnetar in R. However, with a relatively small grid of only 24 different combinations, this already takes a considerable amount of time. Any idea how to improve the code to make grid search way faster?
data_train = rnorm(n = 290)
data_test = rnorm(n = 87)
library(forecast)

set.seed(42)

forecast_naive_nnar = function(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,parameter4,model,h,training_data,testing_data){
  
  model = paste0(model,"_",parameter1,"_",parameter2,"_",parameter3,"_",parameter4)
  h = h
  overall_data = c(training_data,testing_data)
  forecasts = c()
  forecasts_lower95 = c()
  forecasts_upper95 = c()
  begin = length(data_train)
  n_steps = length(data_test)
  forecasts_df = c()
  for (i in 1:n_steps) {
    End = begin+h*(i-1)
    print(End)
    train_set = overall_data[1:End]
    
    if (parameter1 ==0 & parameter2 == 0) {fit <- nnetar(train_set,repeats = parameter4)}
    else if(parameter1 ==0){fit <- nnetar(train_set,size = parameter2,P = parameter3,repeats = parameter4)}
    else if(parameter2 ==0){fit <- nnetar(train_set,p = parameter1,P = parameter3,repeats = parameter4)}
    else{fit <- nnetar(train_set,p = parameter1,size = parameter2,P = parameter3,repeats = parameter4)}
    
    forecast = forecast(fit, PI=TRUE, h=1,npaths = 1000)$mean
    forecastlower95 = forecast(fit, PI=TRUE, h=1,npaths = 1000)$lower[,2]
    forecastupper95 = forecast(fit, PI=TRUE, h=1,npaths = 1000)$upper[,2]
    forecasts = c(forecasts,forecast)
    forecasts_lower95 =  c(forecasts_lower95,forecastlower95)
    forecasts_upper95 =  c(forecasts_upper95,forecastupper95)
  }
  
  nameforecast = paste0("forecast_",model,"_",h)
  forecasts_df = data.frame(cbind(forecasts,forecasts_lower95,forecasts_upper95))
  assign(nameforecast,forecasts_df[1:n_steps,],envir = .GlobalEnv)
  forecast_errors_wn = testing_data - forecasts_df[1:n_steps,1]
  namermse = paste0("RMSE_",model,"_",h)
  RMSE = sqrt(mean(forecast_errors_wn^2))
  print(RMSE)
  assign(namermse,RMSE,envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

parameter1 = c(0,1,6)
parameter2 = sort(c(1,seq(0,30,by=15)))
parameter3= c(12,24)
parameter4= c(10,500)
parameter_grid_nnar = expand.grid(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,parameter4)

for (j in 1:4) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(parameter_grid_nnar)) {
    forecast_naive_nnar(parameter_grid_nnar[i,1],parameter_grid_nnar[i,2],parameter_grid_nnar[i,3],parameter_grid_nnar[i,4],"nn",1,data_train,data_test)
  }
}

